# CKEDITOR.instances['fullHTMLTextArea']

Tags: javascript

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.instances['fullHTMLTextArea'];
if(editor)
{
    editor.destroy(true); 
}
```

Can anyone explain it properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to CKEDITOR API [doc](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.html#.instances)

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.instances['fullHTMLTextArea'];
```

part tells

> Holds references to all editor instances created. The name of the
>   properties in this object correspond to instance names, and their
>   values contains the CKEDITOR.editor object representing them.

and

```
if(editor){
    editor.destroy(true);---> must be
 //editor.destroy();

}
```

[tells](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#destroy)

> Destroys the editor instance, releasing all resources used by it. If
>   the editor replaced an element, the element will be recovered.